# Multi-Page Dash Application

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I'm trying to build a multi page Dash App. When I run the following code, everything works except it won't route to my /dash_1 or /dash_2 urls. Was wondering if someone could help me out.

My structure looks like this:

dash-project/
  app1/
     app.py

app2/
     app.py

server.py
  run.py

My run.py code is

```
from app import server as application
from app import app

import app_1.dash_1
import app_2.dash_2
```

My app.py code is:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
import os
import pandas as pd
import dash
import flask

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from analysis import *

server=flask.Flask(name)
app = dash.Dash(name)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

app.css.append_css({
‘external_url’: ‘https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css’
})
```

My dash_1.py code is:

```
import dash 
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output 
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from analysis import * 

from app import app, server 

app = dash.Dash(name='dash_1', sharing=True, 
url_base_pathname='/dash_1', csrf_protect=False) 

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/ds/app_1/main.csv')

layout = html.Div([
dcc.Graph(
    id='Senators ',
    figure={
        'data': [
            go.Scatter(
                x=df[df['candidate'] == i] 
['contributor_individual'],
                y=df[df['candidate_name'] == i]['contributor'],
                #z=df[df['candidate_name'] == i]['contributor'],
                text=df[df['candidate_name'] == i]['contributorl'],
                mode='markers',
                opacity=0.7,
                marker={
                    'size': 15,
                    'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
                },
                name=i
            ) for i in df.candidate_name.unique()
        ],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            xaxis={'title': 'Contributor '},
            yaxis={'title': 'Contributor '},
            #margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 10},
            #legend={'x': 0, 'y': 1},
            hovermode='closest'
            )
        }
    )
])

layout = html.Div(children=[
html.H1(children='Senators '),

html.Div(children='''
    God Bless.
'''),

dcc.Graph(
    id='main.csv',
    figure={
        'data': [
        {'x':df['candidate'], 'y': df['sectorl'], 'type': 'bar'},
        {'x':df['candidate'], 'y': df['industry'], 'type': 'bar'},
        {'x':df['candidate'], 'y': df['contributor'], 'type': 'bar'},
        ],
        'layout': {
            'title': 'Let Them Eat...'
            }
        }
    )
])
```

My dash_2.py code is

```
import dash 
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd 

from app import app, server  

app = dash.Dash(name='dash_2', sharing=True, 
url_base_pathname='/dash_2', csrf_protect=False) 

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True 

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/ds/app_2/slice.csv')



layout = html.Div(children=[
html.H1(children='Bars'),

html.Div(children='''
    One Bite....
'''),

dcc.Graph(
    id='slice.csv',
    figure={
        'data': [
        {'x':df['Slice'], 'y': df['Score'], 'type': 'bar'},
        ],
        'layout': {
            'title': 'Bars'
            }
        }
    )


])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I can't seem to wrap my head around this - Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass your flask app to your Dash instance.
Like this.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)
```

So try importing server and include it as a parameter in your Dash instances in app1 and app2.
Like so:

```
from app import server

app = dash.Dash(name='dash_1', sharing=True, 
url_base_pathname='/dash_1', csrf_protect=False, server=server)

app = dash.Dash(name='dash_2', sharing=True, 
url_base_pathname='/dash_2', csrf_protect=False, server=server)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help - when I run the code unfortunately I get the following:

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'traverse'

Comment: Probably because you declared dash twice. Remove the declaration at app.py along with the imports in app1 and app2

Comment: Im a little confused - do you mean remove ...                                                           
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server) from app.py and remove                         from app import server from dash_1 and dash_2 ?

Comment: That's right remove the `app= dash.Dash(name, server=server)` in app.py. since you also imported the said app that I want you to remove to app1 and app2. just remove app from the import statement of `from app import app, server`. Change it to `from app import server` only.

Comment: I removed app= dash.Dash(name, server=server) from my app.py file and now have from app import server in both my dash_1 and dash_2 file - however now its simialr to when i originally posted - i dont get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'traverse' message - i just get a general Not Found error ...

Comment: I noticed you didn't link the layout to your app.
`app.layout` etc.

Comment: do you mean in my dash_1 file ---> app_1.layout = html.Div([ ..... ?                    and in my dash_2 file ---> app_2.layout = html.Div([....

Comment: because i just tried this and unfortunately it's still not working : /

Comment: You may also try importing the said dash applications to app.py. and register routes on flask. 

`from app1 import app as app1`
`@server.route('/app1')`
`def dash_app1():`
`return app1.index()`


try checking this out https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/214

Answer (score 0):

@Franrey Saycon is completely right. You were importing too many things. In case this is helpful to anyone, I created a [tutorial that shows how to build a multipage Dash application](https://youtu.be/RMBSQ6leonU), with explanations on folder/file structure and library imports.