# Multi-Page Apps in Dash - dropdown values not recognised in other pages

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, plotly-dash

The dropdown values aren't not being pulled in and displayed when I move to another page.

Can anyone help please?

I have tried to follow the online dash documentation (https://dash.plot.ly/urls) and this post ([Multi-Page Dash Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255660/multi-page-dash-application)) but with no success.

```
import flask
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_auth


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True

url_bar_and_content_div = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])


index_page = html.Div([
dcc.Link('Go to Questionnaire', href='/questionnaire'),
])


intro_page_layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='memory-ouput', storage_type='memory'),
    html.Div([
                html.Div(

                    html.H6("""Select your current industry""",
                            style={'margin-right': '2em'})
            ),

            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='business_area_dropdown',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Academia', 'value': 'academia'},
                    {'label': 'Energy', 'value': 'energy'},
                    {'label': 'Research', 'value': 'research'}
                ],
                placeholder="Select Business Area",
                style=dict(
                    width='40%',
                    verticalAlign="middle"
                )
            )],
        style=dict(display='flex')
    ),

    html.Div([
            html.Div(
                    html.H6("""Are you happy where you are?""",
                            style={'margin-right': '2em'})
            ),

            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='search_preference',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Yes', 'value': 'yes'},
                    {'label': 'No', 'value': 'no'}
                ],
                placeholder="Select Answer",
                style=dict(
                    width='40%',
                    display='inline-block',
                    verticalAlign="middle"
                )
            )],

        style=dict(display='flex')
    ), 

    dcc.Link(
    html.Button('Submit', type='submit', id='submit-button', style={'margin-bottom': '5em', 'width': '110px', 'height':'50px', 'padding': '10px', 'font-weight':'bold'}),
    href='/summary')

    ])


summary_page_layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Summary Page'),
    html.Div(id='results-page-content')
    ])


def serve_layout():
    if flask.has_request_context():
        return url_bar_and_content_div
    return html.Div([
        url_bar_and_content_div,
        index_page,
        intro_page_layout,
        summary_page_layout
        ])


app.layout = serve_layout


@app.callback(Output('memory-output', 'data'), [Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')], [State('search_preference', 'value'), State('business_area_dropdown', 'value')])
def on_click(n_clicks, input1, input2):
    if (n_clicks < 1 or n_clicks is None) and input1 is not None and input2 is not None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    return data

@app.callback(Output('results-page-content', 'children'), [Input('memory-output', 'data')], [State('search_preference', 'value'), State('business_area_dropdown', 'value')])
def on_display(data, input1, input2):
    if data is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    return html.H3('Results are ' + input1 + ' and ' + input2)


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),[Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/questionnaire':
        return intro_page_layout
    elif pathname == '/summary':
        return summary_page_layout
    else:
        return index_page

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

On the summary page, I should have the values chosen by the user from the questionnaire page. Strangely enough, those values are not being displayed on the summary page.

Any help or pointers will be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the dropdown values on disk, in a `flask.session` object or in a `dcc.Store` component. Dash doesn't keep input values from other pages when you switch pages.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It really helped put things in perspective. However, I'm still running into some issues.... I will edit the code above for you to see what I'm doing. Cheers!

Comment: I still cannot get input1 and input2 to be displayed on the summary page... Any idea please? Many thanks!

Comment: No not at all @Falc. I ended up using Flask instead of Dash. Shame....